# Trying to make my Wordpress nav TRULY responsive - Function theme (Elegant Themes)

Tags: css, wordpress, nav, responsive

I'm trying to make my Wordpress nav truly responsive. It's responsive in the sense that once it hits 767px, it switches to a mobile friendly nav, all good.

What I'd like to do though, is make it so that for any screen size between 767px and infinity, it scales up and down to fit appropriately.

Currently, I am managing it by using media query breakpoints, and adjusting the font size and anchor padding.

I've also tried various nav plugins, and they don't seem to do handle this the way I want either.

Is there a way to set some CSS attributes as a percentage, so that as I slowly change the width of the browser, it dynamically adjusts the nav so that it takes up the full width of the nav bar but doesn't wrap onto two lines??

www.thecyclery.net.au

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox to layout your nav.

the key i found was adding flex-grow to your list item.

```
.flex-item {
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

You will have to tailor your current css to suit. And by that i mean you might have to remove some of your styling from your links and add them to the li instead.

my example:
http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/YWwXXY

learn more here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: looking OK so far. Have had a read through some documentation, but one hitch I've come up with is stopping the text (links) wrapping onto the two lines (within the flex item). Idealy I would like to reduce the font size as the page width reduces... any way to do this without resorting to media queries again do you think? Thanks!

Comment: you can stop that by adding "white-space: nowrap;" That forces it to stay on the one line, but you can end up with problems on narrow screens. I've update the codepen to show you how that would work in conjunction with the "text-overflow: ellipsis;" property.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @partypete25 - I'll have a play with that.